# decimal rounding in union of sums?

Tags: sql, decimal, rounding

I'm working on SQLServer 2008 with the following table:

```
id      user      program   seconds
------------------------------------
9999  'user01'    'pr01'       5
```

Column 'seconds' is defined as a decimal(14,0) and the only row in the table is the one shown.

So I try some queries:

Q1:

```
select seconds*0.95 from myTable
union all
select seconds from myTable
```

It gives the result I expect:

```
4.75
5.00
```

Q2:

```
select sum(seconds)*0.95 from myTable
union all
select sum(seconds) from myTable
```

I was expecting the same result as in Q1 but the result I get is:

```
5
5
```

Q3:

```
select sum(seconds)*0.95 from myTable
union all
select sum(seconds)*1.00 from myTable
```

In this case I get the results I expect:

```
4.75
5.00
```

So, I would like to know why Q2 is not getting the expected results. <strike>I have tried the same example with 'seconds' being a decimal(2,0) and works fine so I guess it has something to do with the size of the decimal, but in that case I cannot figure out why Q1 and Q3 work while Q2 does not.</strike>

Comment: I'm trying back with decimal(2,0) and it does not seem to work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `sum(seconds)` is `numeric(38,0)` which makes sense as you could be summing any number of `numeric(14,0)` rows and this avoids overflowing a smaller type.

Multiplying a `numeric(38,0)` by `0.95` (`numeric(2,2)`) in the top part gives a result of `numeric(38,2)` as per the [explanation here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/03/29/564110.aspx).

But the bottom part of the `union` is `numeric(38,0)` so the result as a whole is cast to `numeric(38,0)` which again makes sense as `numeric(38,2)` can always cast to `numeric(38,0)` without error (albeit with a loss of digits after the decimal) but casting the other way won't work at all for very large numbers.

You can cast the bottom part explicitly to `numeric(38,2)` to avoid this.

```
SELECT sum(seconds) * 0.95 AS S
FROM   myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(sum(seconds) AS NUMERIC(38, 2))
FROM   myTable
```